# Stop fixed div above footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a social link menu fixed to the left side of he page like this

```
<footer id="colophon"></footer>
<div>
   <nav>
    <ul id="social">
        <li>Link1</li>
        <li>Link2</li>
        <li>Link3</li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And the css

```
#social{
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
   position: fixed;
   transform-origin: left;
   left: 50px;
   bottom: 22px;
}
```

Now there is the footer and I don't want the menu on top of the footer, instead it should stop above the footer. How can I achieve this? I do not want to simply change the bottom position, instead it should be at 22px but stop above the footer.

Comment: Take a look to the position:sticky property

Comment: @Sfili_81 I already did but cannot get it to work...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a margin-bottom to the social nav element equal to the height of the footer element to ensure it stops above the footer.

```
footer#colophon {
  height: 100px; /* or the height of the footer */
}

#social{
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
   position: fixed;
   transform-origin: left;
   left: 50px;
   bottom: 22px;
   margin-bottom: 100px; /* or the height of the footer */
}
```

Comment: no, first of all the footer is responsive so it does not have a fixed height. Second, this does exactly what I DON'T want: it moves the div up even when the footer is no visible, so there is no difference if I set bottom: 122px or use a margin of 100px. But it should be at 22px from bottom of screen, only once you scroll to the footer it should stop just above it.